# Keep linux-modules-extra updated without installing linux-firmware

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel

I am running Ubuntu 20.10 in a VMWare Workstation virtual machine.

I switched from `linux-image-generic` to `linux-image-virtual` so I could remove `linux-firmware` which is both quite large, and unnecessary on a VM.

I need `linux-modules-extra-$VERSION-generic` to be kept up to date because it contains the VMWare video driver.

The problem I've encountered is that automatic kernel upgrades only install `linux-image-$VERSION-generic` and `linux-modules-$VERSION-generic`, not `linux-modules-extra-$VERSION-generic`.

Is there any way to specify in, say, an `apt` configuration file or system maintenance script that whenever `linux-image-$VERSION-generic` is installed, to also install `linux-modules-extra-$VERSION-generic`?

Failing that, is it possible to install `linux-image-generic` without installing all of its dependencies (the microcode and firmware packages)?

**Edit:**
It appears that it is possible to install [scripts](https://kernel-team.pages.debian.net/kernel-handbook/ch-update-hooks.html) in `/etc/kernel/install.d` or `/etc/kernel/postinstd.d` that run when a new kernel is installed, but if those are invoked by the package manager during an upgrade, attempting to run package manager commands to install additional packages seems like it would likely fail.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue was that virtualized hardware drivers were included in linux-modules-extra instead of linux-modules. I filed a bug to have virtualization drivers moved to linux-modules, which is fixed in Jammy and pending for Impish and Focal.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1960633